# SQL Query doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my first time using SQL Server and I have created these tables:

```
create table Department
(
    D_Number int not null,
    D_Name varchar(20),
    D_MgrSSN int,
    D_MgrDate datetime,
    primary key(D_Number),
    unique(D_Name),
)

create table Empolyee
(
    E_SSN int not null,
    E_FName varchar(20),
    E_LName varchar(20),
    E_Sex varchar(6),
    E_BDate datetime,
    E_Salary decimal(10,2),
    E_Address varchar(50),
    E_Department varchar(20),
    E_SuperSSN int,
    primary key(E_SSN),
    foreign key(E_Department) references Department(D_Number),
)
```

and when I run I get this error:

> Column 'Department.D_Number' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Empolyee.E_Department' in foreign key 'FK_*Empolyee*_E_Depa__0CBAE877'.

Comment: What is the actual query that you're running?

Comment: i use SQL SERVER 2008 , is that what you need ?

Comment: The error says it all, you'r keys `E_Department` is not of same type as `D_Number`. You could change `E_Department` to type `int`.

Comment: Nevermind, I see it.  It won't let you create the Employee table.

Comment: You don't show any research effort. You just tried to run the query and pasted the error without even bothering to figure our what it means.

Comment: this is my first time working with SQL server , so i guess my query knowledge is okay .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I think SQL Server did an excellent job with the error message, it tells you **exactly** what needs to be fixed.

Look at the two fields that you have defined, one is a `varchar(20)` the other is an `integer`.

In order for a foreign key to match it's primary key, it must be of the same type.
Either change both to `int` or both to `varchar`.  Whatever makes sense for your business model.

Answer (score 5):

Your:

```
E_Department is varchar
and
D_Number is integer 
//thats the problem
so make E_Department integer //same data type
```

Answer (score 1):

D_Number is an int and E_Department is varchar(50) they need to be the same for the foreign key declaration to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `E_Department` is `varchar(20)`, but the column that it references, `D_Number`, is `int`. You need to make both of them the same type (`int`, because you called it "Number").

Answer (score 0):

Some Tips:
- Employee is spelled wrong
- You should never use SSN as a primary key because you can not easily index it.
- D_Number is not set as identity to the department table, nor is it set to be unique.

The Problem:
-The types E_Department is a varchar(20) and D_Number is an int so of course it won't work